Colimits over Reedy categories
I am interested in computing a homotopy colimit of a diagram $F: R\rightarrow Spaces$ (landing in CW complexes).
My understanding is that in general, one can compute this colimit by taking the simplicial resolution $\Delta^{op} \rightarrow Spaces$ given by
$$[n] \mapsto 
\coprod_{r_0 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow r_n} F(r_0)$$
Then the original homotopy colimit $colimit(F: R\rightarrow Spaces)$ is homotopy equivalent to the geometric realization of this simplicial space. One can also form the fat geometric realization, where degeneracy maps are ignored.
For example, see p. 16 of https://pages.uoregon.edu/ddugger/hocolim.pdf for this formula.
In my setting, $R$ is a Reedy category, which has two wide subcategories $R_-, R_+$ and a degree function $deg$. I understand that in this case there is a model structure on $Fun(R, Spaces)$ and it is useful to compute cofibrant replacement of $F$ with respect to this model structure.
I would like to avoid taking the Reedy cofibrant replacement of $F$. Instead, I would like to modify the above formula to get a different homotopy colimit. Namely, I would like to form another simplicial space $\Delta^{op} \rightarrow Spaces$ given by
$$
[n] \mapsto \coprod_{r_0 \hookrightarrow \cdots \hookrightarrow r_n, deg(r_i) = i} F(r_0) 
$$
where all the maps $r_i \hookrightarrow r_{i+1}$ are in $R_-\subset R$.
Then I would like the (fat?) geometric realization of this simplicial space to compute the homotopy colimit of $F$.
Is this construction (or a variant thereof) true?
On a more intuitive level, I would like a CW model for the homotopy colimit so that $n$-cells can only arise from $F(r)$ for $r$ satisfying $deg(r) \le n$; alternatively, if $deg(r) = k$, then $F(r)$ can only contribute $n$-cells for $n \ge k$.

Something is going the wrong way. The morphisms in $R_-$ should lower degree, so how can you have $r_0\rightarrow\dotsc\rightarrow r_n$, where $\mathrm{deg}(r_i)=i$?

The whole point of cofibrant Reedy replacements is that the homotopy colimit of a cofibrant Reedy diagram can be computed much more easily: it is simply the weighted colimit $W^\bullet⊗R_\bullet$, where $W^\bullet$ denotes a Reedy cofibrant replacement of the constant functor that sends $R^{\sf op}$ to the terminal space.  No need for a Bousfield–Kan-style formula.   As a side remark, it would be helpful to precisely state (with details) the intended application of the construction, as a good answer might be given much more easily then.

@DmitriP. But my understanding is that the Reedy cofibrant replacement is all about fixing the latching maps (which I think of as degeneracies). If we use the fat geometric realization, then we do not have to deal with degeneracies at all, or take the Reedy cofibrant replacement.

@user39598: I am not sure what “fixing the latching maps” means in this context.  My previous comment pointed out that for Reedy cofibrant diagrams there is no need to construct the simplicial resolutions (as depicted in the displayed formulas) in the first place: the homotopy colimit can instead be computed much more directly as a weighted colimit, without constructing the simplicial resolutions.  In any case, precisely stating the original problem that motivated the question in the main post would be far more helpful that trying to guess what you might need.

@DmitriP. The precise setting is a bit technical but basically I am trying to avoid doing the Reedy cofibrant replacement since it seems a bit difficult in my setting (I have modified the question to emphasize this). However, I realized that in some settings, like simplicial spaces, one can avoid doing the Reedy cofibrant replacement by taking the fat geometric realization instead of the usual geometric realization. I am asking for a generalization of this result, but with a more general Reedy category than the simplex category.

@user39598: There are two steps happening in the main post.  The first step replaces R by its subcategory $R_-$, which is possible if $R_-→R$ is a homotopy final functor, e.g., if $R=Δ^{\rm op}$.

@user39598: The second step then computes the homotopy colimit over $R_-$, which is a direct category.  Of course, one could rewrite this homotopy colimit as a homotopy colimit over $Δ_{\rm inj}$, then take the fat geometric realization, which is a weighted colimit: $|X|=W⊗X$, where $W\colon Δ→{\sf Top}$ satisfies $W_n=Δ^n$.  This is a special case of the above recipe: $W$ is Reedy cofibrant and $X$ is Reedy cofibrant if and only if it is objectwise cofibrant, e.g., a retract of a CW-complex.

@user39598: But then again, the purpose of the intermediate step is not clear to me: one might as well cofibrantly replace the trivial weight by a Reedy cofibrant weight $W\colon R_-→{\sf Top}$, then take the weighted colimit $W⊗X$, which computes the homotopy colimit over $R_-$ as long as $X$ is objectwise cofibrant.  Cofibrant weights $W$ are easy to construct, and for such weights $W_n$ typically has the CW-dimension close to the degree of $n$, fulfilling your request for a “CW model for the homotopy colimit so that n-cells can only arise from F(r) for r satisfying deg(r)≤n”.

@user39598: However, if one insists on following the original recipe as close as possible, it is certainly possible to do so, at least if $R_-→R$ is a homotopy final functor.  The formula in the main post is the Bousfield–Kan formula for computing homotopy colimits over $R_-$, the only condition one needs to impose is that $F$ is objectwise cofibrant.
